# Reproduce output in picture using a logical input list by introducing a bug

Tags: computer-puzzle, real

I came across this picture and thought that this would be a fun programming puzzle to work out. (https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/4hjf4y/ill_take_february_tickets_please)

> [image]
>
> (Clearly, the drop-down should simply have numbers from 0 to 10, but instead has some numbers replaced by the corresponding word, while others have been replaced by the name of the corresponding month.)
>
> **Can you figure out what bug or oversight in well-intentioned code could reproduce this exact output?**

The solution has to make sense (like there ought be a correct month list, number list, etc), but should contain a weird 'bug' that messes up the enumerated results to produce this output.

The solution should show the start state, and explain the steps leading to this final state (a retro-grade puzzle).

do note that it is not as simple as odd = month, even = numbers (the "August" and "September" will fail this check).

good luck and have fun with this thought exercise!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle or related to puzzling.

Comment: @Deusovi I think this could count as a retrograde analysis type puzzle, like [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24888/9718).

Comment: @2012rcampion: Then it's *way* too broad.

Comment: Just wanted to share the piece of gold you can find by reading through the post linked to...  [Stupid phone number entry methods](http://www.dailydot.com/lol/stupid-phone-number-entry-field-challenge/?fb=dd)

Comment: I think this is a valid retrograde analysis puzzle.  The requirement that the intended code should make sense does not make it too broad at all - Can't think of a single reasonable solution, in fact.  It doesn't seem to be something simple like only even months because of the September.  Longer string doesn't work consistently either.

Comment: This question **MAY** be more appropriate over at Programming Puzzles and Code Golf (Disclaimer: I am not an active member of that SE, but I have seen questions of a similar vein over there)

Comment: @GordonAllocman: It is definitely not suitable over there. At PPCG, every question has to have an objective way to determine the winner - usually least number of bytes to solve a coding problem.

Comment: @Deusovi that's not true, Popularity Contest is the 7th most popular tag. That doesn't necessarily mean this question would fit there, just that open ended questions such as this one are accepted there as popularity contest tagged questions

Comment: @GordonAllocman: Popularity contests have been getting downvoted and closed recently and are nearly always off topic - and what you're looking for, "code trolling", was deemed off topic a long time ago.

Comment: @Deusovi ahh okay, it has been over a month since I frequently read the posts there and popularity contest and underhanded were both fairly popular. It seems that has changed as underhanded is now off-topic completely

Comment: @GordonAllocman It's been this way for much longer than just a month.

Comment: @2012rcampion I fear that the "retrograde analysis" tag on the puzzle you link to has misled you. Neither that one nor this one is a retrograde analysis puzzle. Retrograde analysis problems ask questions about a game's history. Whoever will search for retrograde analysis puzzles in puzzling.SE, that puzzle and this one are not what they are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I know we aren't necessarily looking for the actual cause of this behavior, but here are a few observations that may help in understanding it.

First, the (alleged) original discoverer of the bug [stated](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/4hjf4y/ill_take_february_tickets_please/d2qi76f) that he/she encountered it on Fandango. Though his/her original post is about a year old, the layout of the site doesn't seem to have changed. If so, the relevant piece of code is:

```
<td class="numberofTickets">
<select name="AreaRepeater$ctl00$TicketRepeater$ctl00$quantityddl" 
id="AreaRepeater_TicketRepeater_0_quantityddl_0" tabindex="1" 
class="qtyDropDown" name="quantityddl" onchange="javascript: 
adjustTickets(10,3);ticketTotal(this);">

<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>

</select>
</td>
```

There is nothing here that could possibly produce the output in question, and I found no code that modifies how these drop-downs are displayed.

Second, zeisss also stated that he/she was using Chrome and was unable to reproduce the bug with Firefox. Since I couldn't reproduce it with Chromium, I'm starting to get the impression that the real culprit was an extension.

**[And someone, I think, has already found out which one.](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/4hjf4y/ill_take_february_tickets_please/d2q6nja)**

Comment: I mean, what other extension could there be that is shipped with Chrome, not shipped with other browsers, and could cause this?

Comment: Interesting.  But does anyone have a theory on _why_ that extension behaves like this?